# When the British left India, who authorized standstill agreements between Karnataka and Tamil Nadu?

Tags: india, british-empire

When the British left India, Mysore (Karnataka) rulers agreed to instrument of accession by newly formed Indian government. However there were [standstill agreements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standstill_agreement_(India)) which are still leading to [disputes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaveri_River_water_dispute), while also legally maintaining the [princely properties](http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/bangalore/road-widening-will-yield-windfall-for-erstwhile-royal-family/article17853765.ece) with utmost care. India even retained the British Armed Forces and ranks.
Who authorized state standstill agreements

Comment: Could you cite the standstill agreements?  Any of them?  [Please cite all nontrivial assertions](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/633/1401)

Comment: Hyderabad Standstill Agreement of 1947, from National Archives - [**gov.uk**](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C3734925)

Comment: @Jasia - I'm afraid I haven't expressed myself clearly; OP asserts that there is at least one standstill agreement. I'm looking for **a citation to that agreement**.   (my first comment did ask for a definition of standstill agreement, but that has been provided and edited into the question).  Google searches have not confirmed the existence of the referenced standstill agreement. I suspect that "standstill agreement" is a less than useful translation from either OP's native language or from Law, which might as well be a foreign language.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Some of the background is on the Wikipedia page for [Standstill agreement (India)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standstill_agreement_(India)). There is a lot more background on the various prior arrangements that were preserved by the Standstill agreements - some going back to the days of the British East India Company. I'm a bit busy at the moment, so probably won't be able to write a decent answer before the question gets migrated.

Comment: In which case, this question becomes trivial; all the information about authorization is in the [citation provided in wikipedia](https://hidf1.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/the-story-of-the-integration-of-the-indian-states-by-v-p-menon.pdf);

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace So trivial in fact, that people that didn't already know some of the history and background couldn't find the information after 4 hours of searching? ;-)

Comment: Fair point - this is a topic we should discuss on meta - I may add this question to the "Please cite all nontrivial assertions" answer because the biggest obstacle to answering the question was the absence of the citation.  There is a pattern of questions where OP has all the facts needed to answer,  but the facts are not in the question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace To be fair, the OP may not have known any more than they actually posted in their question. They posted a Wikipedia citation for the dispute, but may have picked up the phrase "standstill agreement" from a local newspaper. I knew about it because I've read quite a lot of background on Indian independence and partition, but I suspect that I'm in a fairly small minority in that regard.

Comment: Last comment; I meant no disrespect to OP; I'm happy to see more non-western questions. I'm trying to diagnose a pattern of questions that are difficult to answer - how do we encourage citation of all non-trivial assertions? (without creating novel length comments chains)

Comment: thanks for the links. discovery uk link has not been digitised and cannot be downloaded , the other link(citation) timed out. i managed to get it however. 
page(204) states "At the time of the transfer of power, Mysore had a ministry responsible to the legislature, except in respect of certain 'reserved subjects' which were entrusted to the Dewan. Inspite of all these , in August 1947 the Maharajah executed both the Instrument of Accession and the Stand. still Agreement";
page(331) An example of this is to be found today in Mysore in spite of its excellent traditions.
not fair transition!

Answer (score 1):

Karnataka belonged in Bombay Province (part of Deccan, along with Maharashtra of today)...

The context of the question, the Kavery river dispute, was an issue between the State of Mysore and Travancore. The standstill agreements have no meaning in this regard. It was meant to be a temporary arrangement for legal purposes. It's of no consequence anymore.

When the state boundaries were redrawn, based on linguistics, Karnataka was carved from parts of Mysore state and Deccan states. This made the implementation of river agreement based on the original agreements very complex, as they were based on considerations of overlapping regions.

The original agreements between Mysore and Travancore as parts of British empire expired a long time ago, in 1974. There are no remaining agreements in force.

The Kavery river dispute reflects internal Indian politics now, and has no bearing to the British Raj or any agreements at that time.

**Edit**:
The details about the dispute, which is the context of this question, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaveri_River_water_dispute)

[Wikipedia entry on state reorganization in India post independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_Reorganisation_Act,_1956)

[Wikipedia entry on per-independence structure of princely states in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_princely_states_of_British_India_(by_region))